# is there a membership and role provider that work with the apache AuthUserFile and AuthGroupFile?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is there a project that contains a standard ASP.Net Membership and Role provider that work with the Apache AuthUserFile and AuthGroupFile for authentication & authorization?

Scott Guthrie has a post with almost all known information: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The WebsitePanel IIS Modules project that contains HttpModules that emulate Apache "mod_auth_basic", "mod_authz_user" and "mod_authz_groupfile" modules and works with native .htaccess and .htpasswd files. http://iismodules.codeplex.com/.